# Bird of paradise leaves shriveling, how can I fix it?

Tags: leaves, watering, containers, drainage, light

The leaves on this Bird of Paradise (Strelitzia Nicolai/banana plant) are folding onto themselves and browning at the edges. I'm struggling to figure out why this is happening.

It might be due to the low drainage of its pot, or maybe due to too little or too much watering. I would like help assessing the issue.

**Potting:**

- Initially potted in a ⌀40cm watertight pot without drainage;
- I later took it out and drilled holes under the pot and placed a saucer underneath;
- At the bottom there's a ~3cm layer of leca;
- I used universal potting soil mixed with perlite for extra drainage.

**Light:**

- There is no window with direct sunlight for this plant, so it gets medium-bright semi-direct/indirect light.

**Watering/fertilizing:**

- I water generously once every 6 days;
- I took a reading with a moisture/pH meter today and it came out as damp (one level above moist, nearly the maximum measurement)
- I have not fertilized the plant since I got it 2 months ago;

The plant is currently growing a new stem and leaf.

**Photos:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]